# How do you algebraically derive "x <= 0" from "-x = | x |"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, exponentiation, absolute-value

```
A = "-x = | x |"
B = "x <= 0"
If A, then B.
```

By plugging in numbers or testing ranges less than zero, greater than zero, and equal to zero, I can verify that A implies B. But how do I derive "x <= 0" from "-x = | x |" algebraically i.e. without testing points and ranges?

For example, I tried:

```
-x = | x |
-1 = ( | x | / x ) // cannot divide by x if x = 0
0 = ( | x | / x ) + 1 // [range of right side is [0,2] ]
At this point, we can safely square both sides because the ranges of both sides are non-negative
0 ^ 2 = (| x | / x ) + 1) * (| x | / x ) + 1)
0 = (|x| / x )^2 + ( 2*(|x| / x ) ) + 1
Hold it. (|x| / x )^2 = 1
0 = ( 1 ) + ( 2*(|x| / x ) ) + 1 // assuming x != 0
0 >= ( 1 ) + ( 2*(|x| / x ) ) + 1 // without loss of generality
0 >= ( 2*(|x| / x ) ) + 2
0 >= 2*( (|x| / x ) ) + 1 )
0 >= (|x| / x ) ) + 1
-1 >= (|x| / x ) )
(|x| / x ) ) =< -1
|x| =< -x
```

But I ended right back where I started. I want to get to x <= 0, but the only way I can see how to verify it is like this:

```
0 = |x| + x
assume x > 0
0 = (1 + 1)*x // in this case | x | is equal to x
0 = x // False because positive numbers cannot be less than or equal to zero.
False. x > 0 is invalid.
assume x < 0
0 = (-1 + 1) x
0 = 0*x
True. x < 0  is valid.
assume x = 0
0 = |0| + 0
True. x = 0  is valid.
```

Since there were only three possibilities [x >0, x < 0, and x = 0], 
we have proven that for all possible cases, -x = | x | implies x <= 0. But I want to do it algebraically, without any plug-and-chug of points. How can I prove it algebraically?

Comment: P.S. I don't know Latex so if you could format it properly I would really appreciate it thank you.

Comment: The usual definition for $|x|$ is $|x| = \begin{cases}x,&x \geq 0 \\ -x, &x < 0\end{cases}$, does that help at all?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always true that $|x|\geq0$. So if $-x=|x|$, then this means $-x\geq0$. That is equivalent to $x\leq0$.

Comment: Oh. sqrt(x^2) >= 0 because the square root functions here refers to the positive square root. Even if x were 3*i, where i = sqrt(-1), then the output of | x | would be sqrt(-1), which is positive i. Positive i >= 0, so the definition is even valid for imaginary number, correct?

Comment: @SachaTRed: No, this is only true for real numbers. That's because you can't use "$<$" (or its relatives) with complex numbers. The order is only defined on the real line, not in the plane. You can't even use it with pure imaginary numbers. It leads to contradictions no matter how you try to define it.

Comment: @SachaTRed: It is definitely FALSE that "$i>0$". If it were true, you would then have that $i\cdot i>0\cdot 0$ (i.e., $-1>0$), which is clearly false. Any time you state that "$z>0$" you are implicitly stating that $z$ is real.

Comment: @SachaTRed: You get around this limitation by speaking of the real or imaginary part of a complex number, so you could say "$\operatorname{Re} z<0$" or "$\operatorname{Im} z<0$".

Answer (score 3):

The key, I think, is to appeal to the definition of the absolute value function: $|x| = x$ if $x > 0$, and $|x| = -x$ if $x \le 0$. Your desired implication then follows immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You can approach it by using the definition of absolute value as the square root of $x$ squared.

Given $-x = |x|$, we can then say

$-x = \sqrt{x^2}$.

But for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$, $\sqrt{x^2}\geq 0$. Then,

$-x \geq 0$

$x \leq 0$

Comment: What about imaginary numbers? Does it work for imaginary numbers too?

Comment: No, it's meaningless to use ordering symbols with complex numbers (see what MPW stated). To further understand why $x \le 0$, consider graphing both $y_1= -x$ and $y_2= |x|$. You'll notice that they intersect only where  $x \le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:  if $¬ B  →  ¬ A$ then $A  →  B$.   Since by definition of the absolute value of real numbers, $x>0 →  x=|x|$, it must be that $-x=|x| →  x \leq 0$, and conversely.